# A parametric Gaussian-like integral

Tags: integration

$$ \int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}} dx$$

I'm stuck after doing this:

$$ I = e^{-2ab}\int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-(ax-\frac{b}{x})^2} dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing that, set $x=z\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}},\;dx = dz\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ and apply [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) or just the

> **Lemma**. If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$,
>   $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: And then use [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Relation_to_the_gamma_function) to calculate: $$ I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}\,e^{-2ab} $$

Comment: How to prove this lemma?

Comment: @Mannix: by spliiting the integration range as $(0,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$ and applying the substitution $x-\frac{1}{x}=z$ in both the resulting integrals, leading to an unexpected cancellation.

Comment: By that lemma, $$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{x})^2} dx $$, isn't it?

Comment: @Mannix: no, since $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Why? It's intergal is finite

Comment: @Mannix: really? And what is the value of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}$, if it is finite?

Comment: I'm sorry, it really doesn't converge, but for $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, lemma must work, while $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-1/x+1)^2} $ doesn't converge

Comment: @Mannix: oh, sorry, I mentioned GMT on $\mathbb{R}^+$, but the integration range should have been $\mathbb{R}$. Now fixed.