# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{z^2}{2x^2}}}{x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{ze^{-|z|}}{|z|}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

how to prove this formula $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{z^2}{2x^2}}}{x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{ze^{-|z|}}{|z|}$? i have tried residue theorem, but it seems not to work

Comment: Does this answer your question (after substituting $x=1/y$)? [Given $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819647/given-int-0-inftye-x2dx-frac-sqrt-pi2-evaluate-int-0-inf)

Comment: The LHS is invariant under the transformation $z\to -z$ but the RHS is not.

Comment: @Gary Indeed the OP has forgotten to place the first $z$ between absolute values; but this would mean that a concellation occurs ??

Comment: In fact there seems to be a lot of duplicates. E.g. [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496088), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166709), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787009)...